# I am getting this error when trying to run my bot commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep getting this error when I try to run my bot commands `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.
I've tried to look up the error and try to fix it but nothing comes up that is related to my issue.

Index.js

```
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);

  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
  if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
    console.log("Cant find Commands")
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`)
    console.log(`${f} loaded`);
    bot.commands.set(f, props);
  });

});

bot.on("ready", async() => {

  bot.user.setActivity("Running my code")
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.size} servers!`);
  console.log(bot.commands)
});

bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") return
  if (message.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
  if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);

  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
  let command = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
});
```

The command I am trying to run:

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription("Users Info")
    .setColor("#9B59B6")
    .addField("Full Username", `${message.author.username}+${message.author.discriminator}`)
    .addField("ID", message.author.id)
    .addField("Created at", message.author.createdAt);

  message.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "Userinfo"
}
```

This is just a little bit of my code, let me know if I need to post more.
Here is the full error:

```
(node:26635) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.startsWith is not a function
at Client.bot.on (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/index.js:36:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/media/jeremiah/DISCORDBOT/Discord bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
(node:26635) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:26635) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Can you pinpoint exactly which line throws the error?

Comment: So I fixed message.startsWith error but now it is telling me command is not defined it is in the part "(command.slice(prefix.length));

Comment: Place these lines:
`let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);`
below: 
`let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
let command = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);` and give that a try

Comment: @T.Dirks all of that stuff is already in what are you asking me to change? sorry I can be an idiot sometimes

Comment: That stuff is in there, that's correct. The order is wrong though. Your code in the `on("message", ...` function basically has 3 parts. The first part has 3 `if` statements, the second part has a `let` and an `if`, the third part has 3 `let` statements. You need to switch the 2nd and the 3rd part around

Comment: @T.Dirks Thanks a bunch that fixed it i was working on these few errors for days now

Comment: @T.Dirks how do I make a answer?

Comment: Hi jerry, welcome to Stack Overflow! @T.Dirks can you please put that in an answer, so that jerry can accept it and mark the question as solved?

Comment: I have made it an answer. I didn't do it at first because I wasn't sure that was the solution to the whole problem but as it turned out it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you had your code switched around, change your `on("message", ...` to the following:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
    if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);
});
```